# Find Specific Array Using a Loop

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, loops, count

I'm incredibly new to swift and I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I have no idea of the terminology of what to search.

I've seen how to do this before, but not sure where. I want to be able to loop though my arrays using a count, like the below (but that is not working). So the last number of the array name changes depending on the count. So if myCount = 0 then myArray will equal array_0001_00 and if my count = 6 then myArray will equal array_0001_06, and so on.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something small or if I'm completely on the wrong track.

```
let array_0001_00 = [102,102,102,102,102,102,102,102]
let array_0001_01 = [112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112]
myArray = array_0001_0\(myCount)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I'm currently using the below, which works, but is creating a mountain of code:

```
if myCount == 0 {
    myArray = array_0001_00
} else if myBuilderCountY == 1 {
    myArray = array_0001_01
}
```

Comment: To me its really not clear what you want. Could you explain this better?

Comment: I've edited my question a little to try and explain better, let me know if this is any more clearer, if not, I'll try explain a little more. I'm sorry, I alway find it hard explain myself on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I haven't misunderstood - you have a number of arrays, and you want to select one of them using an index. That looks like selecting an element from an array:

```
let array_0001_00 = [102,102,102,102,102,102,102,102]
let array_0001_01 = [112,112,112,112,112,112,112,112]
let array_0001_02 = [122,122,122,122,122,122,122,122]

let array_of_arrays = [
    array_0001_00,
    array_0001_01,
    array_0001_02
]

let index = 1
let myArray = array_of_arrays[index] // This assigns (a copy of) array_0001_01
```

Comment: Different approach then what I was thinking, but this does exactly what I trying to achieve. Thanks!